# I have to find title but print value how?

Tags: php, regex

My code is given below:-

```
$text = "<div class='title'>Title</div><div class='content'>This is title</div>";

$words = array('Title');

$words = join("|", $words);

$matches = array();

if ( preg_match('/' . $words . '/i', $text, $matches) ){
    echo "Words matched: <br/>";
    print_r($matches);
}

else{
    echo "Not match";
}
```

The problem is that in above code I am finding title but i don't want to print title; I want to print this: "**This is title**" and I am not understanding how I can print this by finding title.

Because title is like keyword that will not change but value which i want to print it is dynamic value and it will change every time, that's why i cannot finding value of title. So how can i do it?

Comment: Don't use regexes. Use [DOM](http://php.net/dom)

Comment: Are you trying to parse an external HTML file?

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) instead.

Comment: Yes, I want to parse external HTML file. Can you please explain how can i do it? Because i am a learner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use regex for parsing HTML. Use a [DOM Parser](http://php.net/dom) instead. In this case, you can use an XPath expression to get the element by class name:

```
$text = "<div class='title'>Title</div>
<div class='content'>This is title</div>";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($text);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$title = $xpath->query('//*[@class="content"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Output:

```
This is title
```

This should get you started. If the title is in a different position, you can modify the expression accordingly to retrieve it.

Comment: I have one more question, If i have multiple keys and don't have class, so how can i do it? Because some time it's happining that there is not mention class and if there is class so class name is different than before.

Comment: @user2965171: What do you mean *multiple keys*?

Comment: If this is come than? -->$text = "<div>Title</div><div>This is title</div><div>Value</div><div>This is value</div><div>Keyword</div><div>This is keyword</div>";

$words = array('Title','Value','Keyword');

Comment: In this example which i send before there is not any class then how can i find?

Comment: @user2965171: How do you know which one is the title? Does it have a unique property? Is it always the second `<div>`? Without details (and clear explanation), I don't think I'll be able to help you.

Comment: I know that first one is title and second is that's value and title will be always same but value is dynamic that will keep changing. Value will always without detail.

Comment: @user2965171: In that case, you can simply use `$title = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(1)->nodeValue;`. [See demo.](https://eval.in/75576)

Comment: Amal Murali You are awesome programmer. Whatever you told me every thing is working. I have one more question and that is last because last condition is remainig that condition is that i have a html page and that page is this page:- "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.runtastic.android.pro2" please visit on this page and now i would like to ask you that i want to find some titles and print values from this page. Those keys are these (1)Updated (2)Size (3)Installs (4)Current Version (5)Requires Android (6)Content Rating  these keys values i would like to find and i have 20 pages.

Comment: Like this page, but problem is that i don't know which one page contain class in value or which one page not, and also it is possible that some keys and values keeps class and some not, and some keeps different class than other key So this is my last question know how can i find know? I have to find just these Key's Values  which i mentioned above.